# SQL query for displaying 3 fields of data using only one integer data entry

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join

I have two separate csv tables with automated data that can be added to via another webpage. This is not static data, it is dynamic and changeable.

**Here is my objective:**

1. Write a web page showing a table of sales (Volume and Price) of each product for a single year.  The user must be able to select the year.

**So far with my query I've gotten this far:**

```
SELECT Products.Name, SUM(MonthlySales.SalesVolume) as 'Total Sales'
FROM Products
INNER JOIN MonthlySales 
ON Products.Id=MonthlySales.Id
GROUP BY Products.Name;
```

On top of that I need to be able to pass in a value (year) with php (which I am capable of doing) to further narrow the search. Am I going about this the right way?

**Example Data:**

MonthlySales.csv

```
Id      ProductCode Month   Year    SalesVolume
23041   121           1     1980    983
23042   121           2     1980    960
23043   121           3     1980    939
23044   121           4     1980    927
23045   121           5     1980    931
23046   121           6     1980    950
23047   121           7     1980    975
```

Products.csv

```
Id,Name,Price
121,Jelly beans,6.79
122,Banana milkshake powder,8.31
123,Edam Cheese,18.73
124,Hairnet,8.05
125,Aubergine jam,2.66
```

By the end I need something like this displayed:

You selected Year: 1980

```
Name                      Price      Volume
Jelly Beans               6.79       11000
Banana milkshake powder   8.31       15000
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use `GROUP BY Products.ID` instead of `Products.Name`. Other than that it looks fine. I think this should probably be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have tried this but get the error message:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Products.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Brain fart on my part. Sorry. I understand now.

Comment: `ON Products.Id=MonthlySales.Id` looks awfully wrong. Perhaps it should be `ON Products.Id=MonthlySales.ProductCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work, so long that `Name` is unique, but it's probably not the best way to do is. This might be more accurate, since you will be basing the group by the PK `Id` rather than the `Name` field.

```
DECLARE @year char(4) = /*your year - datatype should be same as your year col*/;
DECLARE @month int = /*your month - datatype should be same as your month col*/;

SELECT Products.Name, Products.Price, Sales.totalSales AS 'Total Sales'
FROM Products
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MonthlySales.ProductCode, 
                   SUM(MonthlySales.SalesVolume) AS 'totalSales'
            FROM MonthlySales 
            WHERE MonthlySales.Year = @year AND MonthlySales.Month = @month 
            GROUP BY MonthlySales.ProductCode
           ) AS Sales ON Sales.Id = Products.ProductCode
```

Comment: Ok, so does this require me to have a new table called "Sales" with totalSales as a column? I'm sorry if i appear to be blind to what's going on. And in SQL management studio (which is where im testing the SQL queries before imparting it in to my PHP) don't I already have my data type values set for year and month?

Comment: @Haxxx No, it's applying an alias to the `SELECT` query. Pretty much the same thing as what's happening on the `SUM` but happening to a query/table instead. You can actually do the same thing here `FROM Products p` and instead of using `SELECT Products.Name` you could use `SELECT p.Name`. Try the query and let me know how it works. I had to look up the SET portion, I work mostly in T-SQL and MySQL syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Well after taking out the SET portion and instead changing the 'at'year to CHAR(4) and 'at'month to int their was mixed success. The SET didn't appear to work at all, giving errors back? Where as changing 'at'year to CHAR(4) in the query their was no error. But changing 'at'month to int wasn't recognised? And it still give's an error for Sales.totalSales and the Sales next to AS on the bottom row?

Comment: @Haxxx what database are you using? This is important.

Comment: Im using a local University server that uses SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Haxxx Since you included PHP in the original question, I assumed you were using MySQL. I updated the answer. Should work now.

Comment: Aha, we are one step closer! I took out the = from both Declare's and they work fine now. When executed it now displays the column names 'Name' 'Price' and 'Total Sales', however it's still having a problem with "Sales.totalSales". Oh, also, it's displaying 0 rows as of yet.

Comment: And I am using PHP, I just assumed you assigned the query to a variable and use it like that etc like I have been for other webpage database queries.

Comment: You should be setting the `DECLARE` to the year. eg: `DECLARE @year char(4) = '1980'` same thing with the month. Also, the data types `char(4)` and `int` should be the same as what year and month are in the database respectively. (hint: they are probably not `char(4)` or `int` and they are probably both the same thing)

Comment: Oh I see, so I can set the year and month dynamically using post backs with php! I see, great. I'm still struggling to understand where Sales.totalsales comes in, will this work if I run it through php instead of Management Studio or should it work in both? Thumbs up for the answers regardless of whether I succeed with this query or not though, you've made me understand a lot more about my problem.

Comment: Yes, the query is the query. You will have to convert it to a PHP statement to use it properly. Personally I use [HEREDOCS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for SQL in PHP. But, you can also build it into a string `$query = 'select stuff from otherstuff where thisthing=' .  $variablething;` More complex statements (like the one in my answer) tend to work better using HEREDOCS.

Comment: Also, since this is for school you shouldn't worry about it too much. But anything that goes into production to the real world should always have sanitized input to avoid SQL Injection. Sanitizing SQL Statements is **very** important when code is meant for a live audience.

Comment: So I finally got it to work, after all that 'Total Sales' had to be in [] or "" for any alias with a space. And the main problem was we were using ID instead of ProductCode when referring to the MonthlySales table. The PK for MonthlySales was ProductCode and PK for Product was ID. Confusing as they had contradicting names but there you are! Sorted now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Np. Sorry I missed the ProductCode thing. It's generally a good idea to stay away from spaces **in all of programming**, reserve spaces for free text only not anything to do with code or tables. If you need them, you can usually rename them on the output portion only. I know that columns with spaces must be surrounded in `[]` but I did not know that aliases were the same.